# classmethod lambda Python

Tags: python, lambda, mocking, class-method

I'm having a hard time understanding this piece of code.
I understand that we are using some mock instead of the API endpoint to save time on the tests.

What I don't understand is the classmethod(lambda cls: self.preapproval) structure.
What is the point of using a lambda cls if inside the code I don't use at all the cls.

I hope I'm clear enough, I'd be very happy if someone could shed some light on this one..

Thanks a lot.

```
@patch("paypaladaptive.api.endpoints.UrlRequest",
       MockUrlRequestPreapproval)
def test_preapproval(self):
    # I don't understand this code, it is very confusing. Why do I need to use a lambda structure if in the code itself I don't use cls (self.preapproval)
    MockUrlRequestPreapproval.preapproval = (
        classmethod(lambda cls: self.preapproval))
    self.assertTrue(self.preapproval.process())
    self.preapproval = Preapproval.objects.get(pk=self.preapproval.pk)
    self.assertNotEqual(self.preapproval.preapproval_key, "")
    self.assertEqual(self.preapproval.status, "created")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`classmethod`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#classmethod)'s first argument needs to be a function that takes one argument or more. Calling any of this will cause an error:

```
classmethod(self.preapproval) # Not a function
classmethod(lambda: self.preapproval) # Needs one argument
```

This works, but it's too verbose:

```
def get_preapproval(cls):
    return self.preapproval

classmethod(get_preapproval)
```

That's why that code uses lambda.

Probably it can be improved a little bit:

```
classmethod(lambda _: self.preapproval)
```

This makes it obvious that the argument is not needed.

Comment: @GP89 Ah, right, it can take >= 1, because the class needs to be passed. Thanks!

Comment: That makes it MUCH clearer.
But why do we need a classmethod in the firstplace therefore.
Couldn't we put just the lambda?
Or even better, why not do just: MockUrlRequestPreapproval.preapproval = self.preapproval

Comment: I think it's because the rest of the code expects a classmethod. Doing anything else might change the behavior of the class. @cyberjoac

Answer (score 0):

`cls` is just a argument name for lambda ! and you don't use it at all ! `lambda cls: self.preapproval)` yields a function objec for `classmethod` ! , As lambda yields a function object you need to use it for pass `self.preapproval` because of `classmethod`s first argument needs to be a function object !

Comment: How would you write this code to be more readable? Why should it be a classmethod and use a lambda in the first place?

Comment: as lambda yields a function object you need to use it for pass `self.preapproval` because of `classmethod`s first argument needs to be a function object !